# Unable to receive LocalBroadcastManager in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that has an intent extra that needs to be passed to a Fragment using LBM.

Here is what I did so far:

In Fragment. Note that I call the Activity from this fragment.:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.nearbyLocation:
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NearbyLocationActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("location_id", location_id);
                i.putExtra("hyperlocal", hyper_local);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Broadcast message from NearbyLocationActivity to this fragment
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("NearbyLocationEvent");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
                mUpdateUIReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mUpdateUIReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("NearbyLocationEvent")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "intent message= " + intent.getStringExtra("lat"));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mUpdateUIReceiver);
    }


}
```

The Activity:

```
public class NearbyLocationActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnNearbyLocationClickedListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onNearbyLocationClicked(String lat, String lon, boolean reset_coord) {

        Log.d(TAG, "clicked= " + lat);

        Intent i = new Intent("NearbyLocationEvent");
        i.putExtra("lat", lat);
        i.putExtra("lon", lon);
        i.putExtra("reset_coord", reset_coord);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Also, note that the Fragment is not an instance of NearbyLocationActivity. Is from another activity.

The problem is the LBM doesn't get called in the Fragment after onNearbyLocationClicked in the Activity, although I have set the IntentFilter.

I want to get the data from Activity to the Fragment. How do I fix this? Do I need to inlcude this inside manifest?

Comment: Look at the fragment lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating. It looks like you might unregister the listener before any broadcast is made.

Comment: Ok it works after I removed the onPause method. So is it important to unregister the receiver in this case?

Comment: Move registration and unregistration to onCreate() and onDestroy() and you will be set.

Comment: onDestroy() is not guarenteed to be executed. I would rather put in onStop() then.